# AppCenter icon remains in dock even after all the updates have been installed

Tags: appcenter

I do not keep the app in the dock and when there are new updates, it goes to the dock with a small red counter. The thing is that when I install the updates, the icon remains there with its counter. Any ideas on how to fix that ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an AppCenter bug.

Check Github Issue [#390](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/390) to read more about it.

As a temporary fix, you can remove the notifications by issuing

```
killall appcenter
```

on a terminal window.